# pySpark fault tolerant configuration

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running long jobs (+ 3 hours) on a large Spark cluster on yarn mode.
The VMs workers running spark are hosted on the Google Cloud Dataproc and most of them can be destroyed during execution (preemptible VMs that cost less).

When this happens, the job fails because tasks are failing on the destroyed worker with this error in the container logs of the failing worker :

```
Executor is not registered
```

I've tried setting `spark.task.maxFailures` to 1000 but this doesn't seem to be very effective : even though the job finishes, the tasks doesn't seem to be automatically re-distributed and the computation for the tasks assigned to this specific worker seem to roll back to the initial stage.

Would there be a way of having a more fault tolerant configuration that simply excludes unresponsive executors and re-assigns their tasks?

I could include the ressourcemanager logs, nodemanager and container logs if asked but I don't think it would be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a regression in how pre-emptible workers leave the cluster.

The issue is not just failure intolerance. Preemptible workers are created and destroyed continuously throughout cluster's lifecycle. Each time a worker leaves, YARN will wait for 15m for heartbeat before detecting failure and recreating the container. This can make your job run considerably longer.

We will fix this in the next release.

**Workaround:**

The following will force the worker to leave cluster on shutdown.

Create the following script and upload it to a GCS bucket:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo sed -i "s/.*Stopping google-dataproc-agent.*/start-stop-daemon --stop --signal USR2 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile \${AGENT_PID_FILE}; sleep 5s/" \
   /etc/init.d/google-dataproc-agent
```

Lets say you uploaded it to gs://my-bucket/fix.sh

Now recreate your cluster with this initialization action:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create my-cluster ... \
  --initialization-actions gs://my-bucket/fix.sh
```

You can verify this by ssh-ing into the master node and setting up a watch on yarn node list:

```
gcloud compute ssh my-cluster-m
watch yarn node -list
```

In another terminal, issue a cluster update command that reduces number of workers and verify that number of yarn nodes changes accordingly.

Comment: My original question was more "in-general" spark question, that's why I didn't include the dataproc tag. I should have been more specific but I wanted to know if there would be a certain way to checkpoint the finished tasks of the current stage in HDFS with a certain replication so when a node is lost during a long computation with a large number of tasks compared to the number of workers, so we don't have to re-compute all the completed tasks. I will try your workaround but that could possibly lead to leaving only the non-preemptible nodes compute everything at the end of a long job, right?

Comment: @Paul Yes you could end up with only non-preemptibles to do all the work. With preemptible nodes there are no guarantees that you will get the requested number of nodes, depending on availability. In addition, they have a maximum lifespan of 24 hours. As preemptible nodes are lost, Dataproc will attempt to recreate them. Also, for these reasons preemptibles are used as computation nodes only and do not store any data themselves.

Comment: To clarify, as preemptible nodes get automatically recreated, they do so as fresh nodes and would successfully rejoin the cluster even if they previously left the cluster explicitly on shutdown. The same is true of manually scaling the primary worker group down and back up; the workers aren't poisoned from previously getting decommissioned. So adding the workaround doesn't make it any more likely to get stuck on only the non-preemptible nodes at the end of the job, unless you just failed to get new preemptible nodes entirely due to capacity constraints.